# Cant enter PHP value for <textarea>

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have made a page in HTML/PHP and I would like a function to be able to edit some files though the web-page. I have a `<textarea>` tag to do this.

However, I cannot seem to enter any default value to the `<textarea>` through PHP variables.
Here is my code

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>
<textarea name="input">
<?php echo $text; >?
</textarea>
```

But the text that appears is "`<?php echo $text; ?>`"
Please help, I couldn't find help anywhere else.

Comment: First of all you had an error within `<?php echo $text; >?`

Comment: You will find a *great deal* of help in your error log. It would have told you what was wrong in this case, and saved you 10 mins coming here and asking this. You really need to access your error logs when developing with PHP, and/or display them on screen if dev site (not production)

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced your ending PHP tag (`>?` should be `?>`) when echoing the result into the textarea.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>
<textarea name="input">
<?php echo $text; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your php knowledge:

line 5 should be `?>` not `>?`. Then it will be valid.